# Let $X$ is Bernoulli$(\frac{1}{3})$, $Y=4X-2$ compute the cdf $F_{X,Y}$

Tags: statistics

> Let $X$ is Bernoulli$(\frac{1}{3})$, $Y=4X-2$ compute the cdf $F_{X,Y}$

So I started by finding $P(Y\leq y)$

which is $P(4X-2\leq y)=P(X\leq \frac{y+2}{4})$

So I get that

$$F_X(x)=\begin{cases} 0&:& x<0 \\ 2/3&:& 0\leq x< 1\\1&:& 1\leq x\end{cases}$$

And I believe for cdf of $Y$ I get:
$$F_Y(y)=\begin{cases} 0&:& \frac{y+2}{4}<0 \\ 2/3&:& 0\leq \frac{y+2}{4}< 1\\1&:& 1\leq \frac{y+2}{4} \end{cases}$$

So for cdf of $F_{X,Y}(x,y)$
$$F_{X,Y}(x,y)=\begin{cases} 0&:& \min(x,\frac{y+2}{4})<0\text{ or } \max(x,\frac{y+2}{4})<0\\ 2/3&:& 0\leq\min(x,\frac{y+2}{4})< 1\\1&:& 1\leq \min(x,\frac{y+2}{4})\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly $X\sim\mathcal{Bern}(1/3)$ means $\mathsf P(X{=}1)=\tfrac 13$ and $\mathsf P(X{=}0)=\tfrac 23$, with these events mutually exclusive, so $$F_X(x)=\begin{cases} 0&:& x<0 \\ 2/3&:& 0\leq x< 1\\1&:& 1\leq x\end{cases}$$

Secondly, $Y=4X-2$ means …$$\mathsf P(X\leq x, Y\leq y)~{=\mathsf P(X\leq x, 4X-2\leq y)\\=\mathsf P(X\leq \min\{x,(y+2)/4\})}$$

Comment: I made some changes based on your answer, are they correct?